# Unable to render Promotion in SmartTarget with DD4T.NET

Tags: 2013, dd4t, smarttarget, fredhopper

I have created promotion using the targeting tab in CME and to create a view i have followed the approach in this article http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/dd4t-and-sdl-smarttarget-2014-integration.

But Promotion is not displaying on view. Below is the log of AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore; and AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(claimStore);

> Start claimStore : Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.ClaimStore
>   2015-02-05 13:48:03,939 [5] DEBUG Helpers.Logger [(null)] - Start GetTriggers : &taf_request_full_url=http%3A%2F%2Fsmarttargetdd4t%2Findexpage.html&taf_tracking_id=tridion_91ece18d-1231-4291-8053-141e50b048b7&taf_response_cookie_generation=true

Any help regarding the will be highly appreciated

Comment: how does this question differ from http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11034/smart-target-2014-with-dd4t-net exactly? Does it make sense to merge those two or are they different questions really?

Comment: this time i was expecting promotion to display as all the error was resolved and earlier there was error ...any help regarding the same will be highly appreciated

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing what your Promotion triggers on and what the query looks like which is sent to Fredhopper (it's logged so should be easy enough to find). One thing is clear, though: the two do not match. So the Promotion expects certain trigger values and they aren't being set. The real question, then, is what triggers are missing and why. For that we need more information.

Comment: Hi Peter 
Query log output of AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(claimStore);:&taf_request_full_url=http%3A%2F%2Fsmarttargetdd4t%2Findexpage.html&taf_tracking_id=tridion_ceebeb60-83f9-458f-ac59-3019dd2ed658&taf_response_cookie_generation=true

and Trigger type is of Current Date.

Comment: If you have managed to resolve errors relating to earlier questions you posted, please update those questions with resolution - this information can help others.